# How do I force a TextView to be at least one line tall even when blank?

Tags: android, android-layout

Consider this list row for example:

```
┏━━━━━━━┯━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┓
┃       │ Primary Text                ┃
┃  IMG  │                             ┃
┃       │ Secondary Text              ┃
┗━━━━━━━┷━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┛
```

I would like to know how to keep the secondary text box from collapsing on itself when its blank. The image may or may not be taller than the primary text, and both textboxes may span multiple lines.

Comment: Perhaps in the XML you can set the minimum lines for that textview? https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:minLines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// try this attribute on Secondary TextView
android:minLines="1"
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to get around this issue it to use a non-breaking space in the secondary text when it would otherwise be blank. (`'\u0240'`)